# Where to put helper class using Page Object Model in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

I have a following structure in my project:
[image]

**pages** - for describing web-elements on the page with getter and setters.
**tests** - for tests using pages
**resource** - config file with url, username, password

I want to make a class User and use object of this class in the test.
Where should I put it? In which directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be stored in the separate directory, e.g. entities directory.
But not in the pages folder.

Answer (score 0):

It should be kept in pages. Test files and Page Objects must be in different locations.